Unable to utilize the 3D pointcloud topic as an observation source for Nav2 stack
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan
    map_topic: /map

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: False
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      map_topic: /map
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer", "infra_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      infra_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /tb1/camera/points
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      map_topic: /map
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer", "voxel_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /cam7/points
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "turtlebot3_world.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

I'm using the above nav2_params for bringing up the robot with two observation sources. However, the navigation stack is not able to utilize the pointcloud2 message topic '/cam7/points'. The frame link is in the same tree which originates from the 'map'. I confirmed that the new topic is being subscribed by the global and local costmap nodes, using the below message.
root@ml-01:~/kpi# ros2 topic info /cam7/points
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Publisher count: 1
Subscription count: 3


Have you checked:

TF tree is connected to your PointCloud sensor frame?
The QoS settings on the PointCloud?
Can you see the PointCloud in Rviz & that the topic is publishing with content (if not, Nav2 can't either)
That the topic is correct :-)

